# Using a C #define variable as an #include

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have the following code which includes a library based on a #define'd variable:

```
#if LIB_SELECTOR==1
#include "path/to/lib1.h"
#else
#include "path/to/lib2.h"
#endif
```

However, this library needs to be included in a number of source files, and maintaining this conditional across all of them could be problematic and prone to error.  Ideally, I would simply do something like:

```
#if LIB_SELECTOR==1
#define DYNAMIC_LIB "path/to/lib1.h"
#else
#define DYNAMIC_LIB "path/to/lib2.h"
#endif
```

Then, in all of the requisite source files, simply use

```
#include DYNAMIC_LIB
```

I've tried it in my code, and received the error `error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>`. This doesn't give me much hope, but I am wondering what the proper way to solve this problem is.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/ImrW0j); are you sure your source files know the definition of `DYNAMIC_LIB`?

Comment: Assuming no typing errors (misspelled macro names), then you have some sort of archaic (pre-C89) C preprocessor.  Which compiler are you using on which platform?

Comment: Could be the fact that I'm using AVR-GCC?  I don't know why that would follow some ancient version of the spec, but maybe it has slightly different rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have should work, but the files that use `#include DYNAMIC_LIB` have to have `DYNAMIC_LIB` defined first. On a source file that fails, you can test with:

```
#ifndef DYNAMIC_LIB
#error "DYNAMIC_LIB is not defined!"
#endif
#include DYNAMIC_LIB
```

You don't have to maintain that conditional in all your source files. You can create one header file that has the conditional, and let your other source files include that file instead. For example:

```
/* lib_selector.h */
#pragma once
#if LIB_SELECTOR==1
#include "path/to/lib1.h"
#else
#include "path/to/lib2.h"
#endif
```

Then all your other source files would `#include "lib_selector.h"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just put your code into a header file, and just include that header file everywhere.

// CommonHeaders.h

```
#ifndef __COMMONHEADERS_H__
#define __COMMONHEADERS_H__

#if LIB_SELECTOR==1
#include "path/to/lib1.h"
#else
#include "path/to/lib2.h"
#endif

#endif // __COMMONHEADERS_H__
```

// Your many other .h/.cpp files

```
#include "path/to/CommonHeaders.h"
```